# can't get string from strings.xml in appcelerator

Tags: ios, string, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working on Titanium 2.1 and developing a iOS app and I can't get any of my strings in my strings.xml file.
Here's my strings.xml file [link](http://pastebin.com/B71uyPDd)

In my code I have the following:

```
var action = 'created_a_group'; //string at line 24 in strings.xml

var actionLabel= Titanium.UI.createLabel({

    text:Ti.Locale.getString(action), 
    color:"#666666",
    font:{fontSize:12}, 
    left:8

});
```

but when my label is shown, the correct string isn't shown, instead `created_a_group`appears. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the file in the correct folder?

It should be in the i18n folder outside of the Resources folder.  It should also be in the appropriate language folder.  Though I haven't tried this, are you use that your device is in the correct language setting to pick the appropriate sting.xml file?  For example, if you have the string.xml file in the /i18n/en folder, but have it set to a different language on the device, perhaps it can't locate it for that language.

Comment: I'm using the emulator, as far as I know the emulator uses the OS language as default language. Also I have my strings.xml in the i18n/en folder(since my OS language is english), which is located in the root folder of my project. In theory it should work but it isn't.

Comment: Thank you! I copied it from another project to the resources folder accidentally and your answer solved my problem.